# Autohotkey: remap ctrl + {

Tags: autohotkey

I want ctrl + { to work as the home key.
This doesn't work:

```
^{::Send {Home}
```

I guess the { needs to be escaped?

This also doesn't work: (it generates an error on loading the script)

```
^{{}::Send {Home}
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The first one is the correct syntax. How do you type `{` on your keyboard? On mine it is Shift+[ so to execute your hotkey I actually have to type Ctrl+Shift+[. If it's the same for you and you don't want to press shift you can use `^[`.

Comment: I can type  { without shift or alt key.

Comment: Try the steps listed [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) and using the resulting virtual key code (`VKnn`) for `{` to make the hotkey. Sidenote, what keyboard layout are you using (guessing Dvorak programmer or Latin America)?

Comment: Thanks. That worked: `^SC028::Send {Home}`. I have a custom layout (https://github.com/r03/azerty). Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I you make an answer of your comment, then I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the steps listed [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) to find the scan code and virtual key code of the `{` and then use either of those (`SCnnn` or `VKnn`) in the hotkey definition.

Even though that works I was curious why the `^{` doesn't work for your layout, so I tried using it and seeing if AHK's key history showed `{`, which it does. I took a look at AHK's source code to see what's happening, and I think it comes down to the return value of [`VkKeyScanEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646332(v=vs.85).aspx) called with { and your layout, which is 0x0634, i.e., <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>. I hadn't noticed that <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>, and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> all produce { in your layout before this, so I tried the `^{` hotkey again and sure enough it fires with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>. So it seems it's [just a limitation of `VkKeyScanEx`](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/03/26/560595.html): even if multiple combinations map to some character only one of them can be returned. In your .klc file, wherever LEFT CURLY BRACKET first appears will be the combination that `VkKeyScanEx` returns. I don't know if you use the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> combinations for {, but if you remove them from your layout the `^{` hotkey should work for just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! It’s correct that I have multiple { keys on my layout. The problem is that the normal azerty and the Apple azerty have different locations of some characters and I tried to be compatible with all layouts and I also changed some unused keys with things like { to code faster. But it works with the scan code so I’m happy with the solution.